# Mysql group for intelligent activity streams with timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build an intelligent news feed for users on my website.

The news feed shows photos of what a users followers have liked or commented on. Also it shows people who a user's followers have just followed. Sort of like news feed on Instagram.

I have the following Tables:

user
follow
comment
notifications
photo

```
 user table has the following fields:
 userid, username, avatar

 followtable has the following fields:
 userid( the user), followingid(whom the user is following) datefollwed

 comment table has the following fields:
   comment, commentid, datecommented, commenter, photoowner

  Notifications table has the following fields:

   id, type( type could be 1 for like, 2 for comment, 3 for new follow), datenotified, who(who made the action), whom( whom the action is affecting), what ( the id of the action so like the commentid, likeid, can be 0 for followid)

  prhoto table has the following fields:
   photo( filename), photoid, dateuploaded, userid (who uploaded it)
```

Now I want to build an intelligent news feed that I can echo out through a multidimensional array in php.

For instance

if John with user id 1 is following Anne (2), Jane(3) and Mark(4)

And Mark like 5 photos of Bruce(5), commented on Jane' photo and followed Anne
and Jane like James(6) photo and Johns (8) photo
and Anne followed Mary(7)

I would want to be able to query a result that groups similar action by users so it would read something like

```
Mary liked 5 photos of bruce (and show the first photo in the sub array) 
Mary commented on Janes photo ( with the comment)
Mary followed Anne
Jane like 2 photos - ( James photo) and ( Johns photo) 
Anne followed mary.
```

I have a query that is able to get the results but it is not intelligent. I would want to make it group by the user axis. Also the query that I have does not show whom the followers action id performed on

So i would Mary liked 5 photo of (5 the id and not the name)

Here is my query

```
 SELECT userTable.username, 
        userTable.avatar, 
        userTable.userid,
        userTable.verified,
        followTable.followingid, 
        notificationsTable.who,
        notificationsTable.whom,
        notificationsTable.what,
        notificationsTable.id,
        notificationsTable.timestamp,
        notificationsTable.type,
        notificationsTable.status,
        notificationsTable.date,
        commentTable.comment,
        commentTable.commentid,
        photoTable.photo,
        photoTable.title,
        photoTable.postid 
 FROM userTable 
 INNER JOIN followTable 
 INNER JOIN notificationsTable 
    ON followTable.followingid = userTable.userid 
       AND notificationsTable.whom = followTable.followingid 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN photoTable ON shareTable.postid = notificationsTable.what 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN commentTable 
    ON commentTable.commentid = notificationsTable.commentid  
 WHERE followTable.userid = '1' 
 order by notificationsTable.date
```